# Complex number and Inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of real polynomials of degree ≤2.

Now let $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ be a complex number, which is not a real number.

1) Show that for all $p,q \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ that:

$$p(\lambda)\overline{q(\lambda)}+p(1)q(1)+\overline{p(\lambda)}q(\lambda) $$

is a real number.

2) Show that a polynomial $p\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$, which is not $0$, cannot have both $1$ and $\lambda$ as roots.

---

1) I can show that it is a real number by taking the conjugate of the entire equation and prove that it does not change: 
$\overline{p(\lambda)\overline{q(\lambda)}+p(1)q(1)+\overline{p(\lambda)}q(\lambda)} = \overline{p(\lambda)}q(\lambda)+p(1)q(1)+p(\lambda)\overline{q(\lambda)}=p(\lambda)\overline{q(\lambda)}+p(1)q(1)+\overline{p(\lambda)}q(\lambda) $

Which means that it must be a real number as it does not change under complex conjugation, is it correct?

2) I hope someone can show how to this part or at least give a hint as to how it should be done.

Comment: The first part of the question concerning $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and the inner product seems irrelevant to what you're actually asking.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, there are more questions regarding the use of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ in the inner-product-space $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and since I had already done them in LaTex, I thought I might as well include the beginning - but yeah a bit irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $1$ and $\lambda$ are roots, then $\overline\lambda$ is also a root and, since $\lambda\notin\mathbb R$, you would have a non-null polynomial with degree less than $3$ with $3$ distinct roots, which is impossible.